# Convert matplotlib graph to bokeh timeline graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, bokeh, timeline

I am trying to plot a timeline graph using bokeh library.

[image: The image is the result of python code below]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

with open('syscall.csv','r') as csvfile :
    rows = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=','))[1:]
    #rows.sort(key = lambda x: int(x[7])) 
    for row in rows:
        print(row[6])
        alfa=0.8
        renk = 'g'
        start, end, data = int(row[6]), int(row[14]), int(row[5])
        x = [start, end]
        y = [data, data]
        plt.plot(x, y, label=row[0], marker='o', color = renk)
plt.xlabel('time(milliseconds)')
plt.ylabel('Amount of Data(bytes)')
plt.title('VFS and EXT4 layer READ/WRITE graph')
plt.legend(['VR = Red, ER=black, VW=blue, EW=green, vr=%d, er=%d, vw=%d,ew=%d'%(vrc,erc,vwc,ewc)],loc='lower left')
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.show()
```

I am trying to use timeline graph of bokeh effectively in order to visualize my data. Can anyone help me regarding this issue or any advice is welcome.

Kind regards,
Thanks

Comment: Do you know that bokeh and matplotlib are two different packages, both mad to create figures? I ask because I do not see any bokeh import and no code that looks like bohek. Right now I am confused by your question.

Comment: Yeah I know, I would like to convert this code to bokeh timeline graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to use a bokeh plot instead of matplotlib you have to organize your data. I can not do it for you, because I don't have your file. Below is a prototype to plot some data points as circles you are welcome to use. If it is not what you wanted, please check out the bokeh [gallery](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery.html), because there are some goog examples.

```
from bokeh.plotting import output_notebook, figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

output_notebook()

data = ColumnDataSource({'x':[1,2,3], 
                         'y':[10,30,20],
                         'color':['green', 'red', 'yellow']
                       })

p = figure(title='VFS and EXT4 layer READ/WRITE graph',
           x_axis_label = 'time(milliseconds)',
           y_axis_label = 'Amount of Data(bytes)',
          )

p.circle(x='x', y='y', color='color', source=data, legend_label='data')

show(p)
```

Comment: ``` import csv
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import output_notebook, figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
output_notebook()
bilgi = pd.read_csv('syscall.csv')
data = ColumnDataSource({'x':bilgi['subm_syscall_ts'],  
                         'y':bilgi['size'], 'color':['green'] })
p = figure(title='Timestamp to Comm graph',
           x_axis_label = 'time(milliseconds)',
           y_axis_label = 'Comm',
          )

p.circle(x='x', y='y', color='color', source=data, legend_label='data')
show(p) ```

Comment: The code works fine, but I want to add a range on x axis. Like : data = ColumnDataSource({'x':bilgi['subm_syscall_ts'] ... bilgi['comp_syscall_ts'], how can I implement it on bokeh library.

Comment: If you want to merge to lists in python, than you can easily add two lists with a plus. Please try
`data = ColumnDataSource({'x':bilgi['subm_syscall_ts'] + bilgi['comp_syscall_ts']})`.
If you want to to plot multiple data on the same x-axis you havt to build a loop.